# Websphere server/hibernate memory leak?

Tags: hibernate, memory-management, jdbc, websphere

I am running Websphere 7.0 form RAD. When I run it without a JDBC datasource defined for Hibernate to read from, it seems to work fine. But if I add the datasource, it starts using more and more memory until the inevitable OutOfMemoryError. I'm frankly stumped. Anyone have any ideas for troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more information. Hibernate itself takes more memory, could cache a lot of resources. Provide database driver and your hibernate settings.

1. You can first try increase -Xmx java
   parameter to few gigabytes.
2. Next check all issues with driver
   and settings - something like this
   [link text](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2398604)
3. Then profile your application to
   possible memory leaks (not closing
   result sets etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I changed the server heap size and that fixed it.